# Как сделать аналогичное меню wordpress следующего вида?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

У меня есть верстка вида.
Как задать меню такого вида в Wordpress?

```
  <nav class="top-nav">
      <a href="">О студии</a>
      <a href="pricing.html">Стоимость работ</a>
      <a href="">Галерея работ</a>
      <a href="">Важное о наращивании</a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть функция для генерации меню

```
wp_nav();
```

в качестве параметров она принимает много всякой всячины, реально как правило нужно только 'name'. CSS правится под сгенерированную вёрстку.

Comment: А как ей подствить эти параметры. Проблема в том что он пихает div

Comment: В параметрах можно сделать так, чтобы он не генерил лишних тэгов. Но это неправильный путь. Лучше пусть генерит HTML как ему удобно,  а CSS настрой так, чтобы отображалось как тебе нужно.